# Given a number N, return the highest number <= N that's divisible by 3

Tags: php

if the number is Divisible of 3 then return yes if it is not then always subtract one until the number will be able to divide on 3 for example 5/3 is not Divisible of 3 so what I wanted to say is I should subtract from 5 until it will be 3 and in this case 3 is a Divisible number of 3.

this is the code I have tried but it doesn't work properly

```
$num = 5;
if($num%3==0){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'No';
    $num= $num-1;
}

echo $num;
```

Comment: So if it's not divisible of 3, You want to make it any number divisible on 3 or specific number?

Comment: I think when you said "abstract", you probably meant "subtract".

Comment: @Graham yes this is what I meant.

Comment: @Dan Yes, this is what I wanted to do (divisible on 3)

Comment: Check the answers and accept the working one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** For cleaner code in this specific instance, [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51576479) (below) uses a better pattern. I would actually recommend using his, since it avoid unnecessary loop repetitions.

---

I think what you're looking for is a [while loop](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php):

```
<?php
$num = 5;
while(TRUE) {
  if($num%3 == 0) {
    echo 'Yes';
    break;
  } else {
    echo 'No';
    $num = $num-1;
  }
}
?>
```

The `break` statement is particularly important because it ensures the loop doesn't run indefinitely.

Comment: @Simo Just a note, I actually think Dan's answer (in modified form, with `$num -= $num % 3`) is better, and this is the one I would recommend using. I just wanted to show the use of a while loop in PHP, since I thought it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you mean?

```
$num = 5;

//If number is divisible on 3.
if( $num %3 == 0 ){
    echo 'yes';

//If number is not divisible on 3.    
}else{
    echo 'No';
    //Make the number divisible of 3.
    $num += (3 - ($num% 3)) % 3;
}

echo $num;
```

Comment: I was using the OP's `subtract from 5 until it will be 3` literally, but this is probably a cleaner implementation. The only thing I would recommend is to make the $num modification simpler in the no condition: `$num -= $num % 3`. Also, you have an undefined variable `variable` in this code.

Comment: @Dan also your code is working properly but just the first example it doesn't but with the condition ($num -= $num % 3) then it worked, thank you

Comment: @Simo, There was an undefined variable, I edited the code

Comment: @Graham, you are right, But if the number is 1 `$num -= $num % 3`, Would return `0`

Comment: @Dan I always check my answer on tio.run (or sometimes other sites when necessary) before I submit. It might help you avoid such errors in the future.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem you mention now, and it's actually a problem with my current code... honestly, instead of doing a bunch of confusing operations, I would just do a check `if($num < 3) { $num = 3 }` if the minimum should be 3. It's clearer and probably more efficient.

Comment: But actually, I don't think the OP specified that the minimum had to be 3. All the OP said was `subtract one until the number will be able to divide on 3`.